# What is the dimension of a paper size?

Tags: terminology, paper-size

I was looking up tolerance values for DIN paper sizes and was confused what is meant by *dimensions*. On every site, I could only find the pasted text [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#A_series):

> The tolerances specified in the standard are
>
> - ±1.5 mm (0.06 in) for dimensions up to 150 mm (5.9 in),
> - ±2 mm (0.08 in) for lengths in the range 150 to 600 mm (5.9 to 23.6 in) and
> - ±3 mm (0.12 in) for any dimension above 600 mm (23.6 in).

Does *dimension* mean width, height or a combination of both?

For example DIN A5 is 148 mm × 210 mm. Is it below or above 150 mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

148 mm × 210 mm means one side is 148 mm ± 1.5 mm and the other side is 210 mm ± 2.0 mm.

Comment: That makes perfectly sense. I was thinking of dimension as one unit rather than looking at each value separately.